# How to destroy the form backing object after its work is done in spring?

Tags: java, session, object, spring-mvc, redirect

I am facing a strange problem, I have one from which is backed by object, now the problem is that the value of that object still persists once the work of the particular is done. Here is my code snippet

1) Login.jsp

```
<form:form action="login" method="POST" modelAttribute="login">
        <table>
            <tr><td>User Id:</td><td><form:input path="userId"/></td><td><font color="red"><c:out value="${userIdError}" /></font> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password:</td><td><form:input path="userPassword"/></td><td><font color="red"><c:out value="${userPasswordError}" /></font></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="newUser">New User</a></td><td><a href="forgotPassword">Forgot Password</a></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

2) Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("login")@Valid Login login,BindingResult result, Model model,HttpServletRequest request)
{
      //performing some validations
     if(obj.getUserPassword().equals(login.getUserPassword()))
    {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("sessionValue", login.getUserId());
        return "home";
    }
@RequestMapping(value="/logout")
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        System.out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionValue"));
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        return "redirect:index";

    }
```

3) Home.jsp

```
<body>
    Home Page for registered user sir
    <font color="red">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${sessionValue==null }">
            <jsp:forward page="/index"/> 
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            we have the persisted value ${sessionValue }
        </c:otherwise>
```

Now the problem is after login I am coming to `Home.jsp` and if I hit the `logout`, I am redirected to `Login.jsp`. But if hit the back button on browser I am redirected to `Home.jsp` page, everything is fine till here but once I refresh ideally I should be redirected to `Login.jsp` but my app is again going to controller fetching the last loginId and loginPassword I entered for login, setting the session. How to avoid it. I hope I was clear.

NOTE:- the problem doesn't come if I logout from some other page, hit logout

```
Login->Home page->Some Other Page->Logout->Hit back button->Some Other Page->refresh->Login
```

This problem occur only if

```
Login->Home page->Logout->Hit back button->Home Page->refresh->Remain on Home page and session maintained
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the method that handles request for "/home"? I'm interested in seeing how that method checks whether the user has been authorized.

Comment: @SerotoninChase: I have already posted the code. I am simply fetching tha data from hibernate and checking if the userId entered by user is equal to the userId present in database